# subdifferential in context of scalar product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to understand, why the following definitions of the subdifferential are equivalent:

A functional $ v^∗$ in the dual space $V^* $is called subgradient at $x_0$ in $U$ if for $\forall x \in U $ 
   $$ f ( x ) − f ( x _0 ) \geq v ^∗ ( x − x_0 ) $$.
The set of all subgradients at $x_0$ is called the subdifferential at $x_0$ and is denoted $\partial f(x_0) $.

Another definition of the subdifferential has the same settings except:
$$ f ( x )\geq  f ( x _0 )+  <v ^∗ ,x − x_0 >$$

How do I get to the scalar product?

Comment: Some authors use $\langle \phi, x \rangle$ to denote function application $\phi(x)$ when $\phi$ is a linear functional. Might that be the discrepancy?

Comment: @DavidKraemer: $v^* (x-x_0)$ is meant to be  $v^*  \cdot (x-x_0)$ . There are two factors?

Comment: $x-x_0$ is an element of $V$, so $v^* (x-x_0)$ or $\langle v^*, x - x_0 \rangle$ would be the application of $v^*$ to $x -x_0$ in a function sense.

Comment: @DavidKraemer: So you can define: $v*(x):= <v*. x> $

Answer (score 1):

The inner product notation here represents the duality pairing (see also duality mapping) between $V$ and $V^*$. As David Kraemer pointed out, one can take $\langle \phi, x\rangle = \phi(x)$ for $x\in V$, $\phi\in V^*$ as a valid duality pairing.

Comment: So I get a scalar product with elements from different spaces. The same problem occurs when you conisder the follwing set: $B= \{  v^* \in V^*| \forall x \in U: v*(x)=0\} = \{  v^* \in V^*| \forall x \in U: <v*,x> =0\}   $

Comment: So $v*(x):= <v*. x> $ Did I see that right?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, yes.

Comment: What is the problem with the definition? It is only a rule of thumb.